# Static NAT using IP address from different address space

Tags: cisco, routing, nat, ospf, troubleshooting

[image: Network]

How to do NAT if I need translate PC IP to IP address f.e. 130.130.130.130?

I set **ip nat inside** and **ip nat Outside** interface and there is also **OSPF** between routers and server.

I use **ip nat inside source static 192.168.0.100 130.130.130.130**

I know that I need to add network 150.150.150.0/24 because of routing, I tried assign this network to LoopBack0 and add this network to OSPF, but it still no working. What I need to do?

Running config border :
[Config](http://pastebin.com/cTuKtszi)

Comment: Please provide the configuration of the router that is doing NAT.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/cTuKtszi

Comment: Can 192.168.0.100 ping the other router (the one not doing router)? What does "sh ip route 130.130.130.130" on the non-NAT router display? Can you post the non-NAT router configuration and "show ip route"?

Comment: No i cannot ping upper router from PC.
Config upper router: http://pastebin.com/n5BgUQCq

Here is routing table upper router: http://pastebin.com/ZPs3T7u8

Comment: I think that there is problem because of Loopback0 where is network 130.130.130.0/24. In NAT router in routing table is network 130.130.130.0/24 directly connected, but in upper NON-NAT router is in routing table 130.130.0.0/32... why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-NAT router is missing a route for the address 130.130.130.130.

Try injecting the required route as static route and then redistribute it into OSPF of NAT router:

```
router ospf 1
 redistribute static subnets

ip route 130.130.130.130 255.255.255.255 null0
```